# modification color Awesome

Tags: css

I have an icon Awesome which is an envelope... I will wish to get the same result below.

In my code, I don't have this border blue and a background-color white.

[image]

I forgot a property?

```css
    .subtitles{
 height: 120px;
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 38px;
}

.subtitle-right{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 70px;
  display: flex;
 


}


.fa{
 font-size: 23px;
    color: blue;
    margin-right: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="subtitles">
 <div class="subtitle-right"><i class="fa fa-envelope 5x"></i>Info@drivingschool.com</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe it's not the right icons set, what do you think? It's like asking why a bicycle doesn't look like a motorcycle...

Comment: The icon of font awesome is different.

Comment: even using class "far fa-envelope" instead of "fa fa-envelope" (eg regular instead of solid) will get you closer. But at the end of the day the underlying icons are just not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to be able to do it exactly: the icon used in your screenshot is fundamentally different than the ones made available by FontAwesome.

However you are using FontAwesome's "solid" icons -- you can get a *little* closer by using their [regular](https://fontawesome.com/icons/envelope?style=regular) icon instead. To do this, change the class `fa` to instead `far`.

To change the color, use the `color` property to adjust the font color.

The only thing I changed in the code below is the class name in the HTML.

```css
.subtitles{
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 38px;
}

.subtitle-right{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 70px;
  display: flex;
}

.far {
  font-size: 23px;
  color: blue;
  margin-right: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="subtitles">
  <div class="subtitle-right"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i> Info@drivingschool.com</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your help. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try this **CSS**:

```
.fa{
    font-size: 23px;
    color: White;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 0px 1px;
    margin-right: 14px;
}
```